# Terraform cloudfront permission to assign Lambda@edge

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

I have come accross this issue while trying to create a cloudfront distribution that uses a lambda@edge for cognito login.

I create the aws_cloudfront_distribution resource with the lambda configured, as expected the lambda gets created first so the cloudfront module can use the lambda ARN.

now for the issue im facing.

Terraform throws an error saying the aws cloudfront principal does not have the lambda permission to "get lambda" which is correct.

I decided to copy a module I have from another project but the aws_lambda_permission resource needs the arn from cloudfront distribution for the "source_arn".

So far im stuck with in the loop --> cloudfront needs the lamda_permission to assing the function.. and the lamda_permission needs the cloudfront arn to be created.

How can I go around this issue??

Is there another way of doing it??

If code is needed I can upload it

Tried hardcoding values that are not defined by aws

Comment: Yes, code is needed as only reading the text cannot help with reproducing the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing the error message, but also the code itself, a [mcve]. We are not clairvoyant, so we cannot help you to debug code you do not show us. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. Please [edit] the question accordingly.